# Difference between JavaScript form submit and a form containing a submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, struts

I need a theoretic clarification...What's the difference between JavaScript form submit and a form containing a submit button?

(I'm using the framework [Struts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts), but I think it doesn't affect the behaviour.)

I mean, this is my example, what's the difference between submit a form with a `input type="submit"`?

```
<html:form action="search.do?method=mySearch" method="post" styleId="searchFilterForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="myfield" value="">
    <table border="0" class="filterclass" width="530px">
        <tr>
            <td class="filterheader" align="center">
                <input type="submit" onclick="doMySubmit()" name="MyList" value="SEND" class="button actionbutton" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html:form>

function doMySubmit() {
    var myform = document.getElementById('searchFilterForm');
    myform.myfield.value = "Hello World";
}
```

And submitting the form with a submit inside JavaScript?

```
<html:form action="search.do?method=mySearch" method="post" styleId="searchFilterForm">
    <table border="0" class="filterclass" width="530px">
        <tr>
            <td class="filterheader" align="center">
                <input type="button" onclick="doMySubmit()" name="MyList" value="SEND" class="button actionbutton" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html:form>

function doMySubmit() {
    var myform = document.getElementById('searchFilterForm');
    myform.myfield.value = "Hello World";
    myform.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most notable difference is that when submitting a form by clicking a submit button there'll be a request parameter corresponding to the button that was clicked. So, in your example, with the submit button there'd be a request parameter with a name of `MyList` and a value of `SEND`. If you call `form.submit()` in JavaScript there won't be.

So if you called `request.getParameter("MyList");` on your server-side, with the first method that will return a String with the value SEND and with the second it will return `null`. This becomes important when you want to control the flow through your Action based on whether or not the form has been submitted, or even which button was used to submit the form (if you had several).

Comment: The question is why is the behavior as such? Why does the JS form submit not send the button? Is this by design or a bug? If the former, why was it done this way?

Comment: @user3621633 A form can have multiple submit buttons. Which one should it send the parameter for?

Answer (score 1):

If your user disable javascript, he can't submit the form.
It's a better practice to add a type submit for accessibility.
More information [on this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23440/why-is-it-inaccessible-to-create-a-form-with-no-submit-button)